# Show row when count is 0

Tags: sql, t-sql, count

I have such a table:

```sql
|users_id  | request_at | status    | banned |
| -------- | ---------- | --------  | ------ |
| 2        | 2013-10-01 | cancelled | No     |
| 3        | 2013-10-01 | cancelled | Yes    |
| 4        | 2013-10-01 | cancelled | No     |
| 5        | 2013-10-02 | confirmed | No     |
| 6        | 2013-10-03 | cancelled | No     |
| 7        | 2013-10-03 | cancelled | No     |
```

and I would like to count how many of rows have status != confirmed and where banned = No for particular day. But I would like to also have value 0 where the condition doesn't match.

```sql
select 
    distinct (COUNT(users_id) OVER (PARTITION BY request_at)) AS count_ban,
    request_at
    from Alll 
    where banned='No' and status != 'confirmed'
```

Result:

```
| count_ban | request_at |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 2         | 2013-10-03 |
| 3         | 2013-10-01 |
```

It shows me correct value, but I would like to also see row

```
| count_ban | request_at |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 0         | 2013-10-02 |
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `COUNT` with `SUM` combined with a `CASE..WHEN` *expression* and moving the conditions of `WHERE` clause there should do the trick:

```
select 
    distinct 
        SUM(CASE WHEN banned='No' AND status != 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY request_at) AS count_ban,
    request_at
    from Alll
```

And you could consider using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN banned='No' AND status != 'confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_ban
, request_at
FROM Alll 
GROUP BY request_at
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just fixed that

Comment: Why `distinct`?

Comment: @Charlieface ..to prevent multiple identical rows in the result because we dont have grouping. Indeed, I'd prefer ´group by´, so I added this to the answer as well

Comment: Yes but seems to be a misunderstanding of how `distinct` works. The brackets around `SUM` do nothing as `distinct` works over all columns

Comment: This will not produce a row for any dates not in the original data.

Comment: What is this "`SWITCH..CASE` statement" you write about? I'm familiar with the [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ in T-SQL. Perhaps you could cite the documentation for `SWITCH..CASE`.

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant CASE ..WHEN

Comment: @PatrickHurst that's right. The question doesn't mention anything that missing dates should be added in the result

Comment: @Charlieface I know how distinct works, the brackets are just copied from the question

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, I removed the brackets ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```sql
With my_dates as (
    Select distinct(request_at) d from Alll 
),
my_banned as (
select distinct (COUNT(users_id) OVER (PARTITION BY request_at)) AS count_ban,
    request_at
    from Alll where banned='No' and status != 'completed'
)
select my_dates.d, ISNULL(my_banned.count_ban, 0)
  from my_dates
  left join my_banned on (my_banned.request_at=my_dates.d)
```

`my_dates` - list of all dates with requests, `my_banned` number of banned in days when bans happened at least once.

Comment: This will not produce a row for any dates not in the original data.

Comment: @PatrickHurst, should it? I don't see any pointer to this in question.

Comment: A good answer answers the question fully, taking into account as many pitfalls as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join to include the dates that do not have any rows that match the condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.users_id) AS count_ban, d.request_at
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT request_at
  FROM Alll
) d
LEFT JOIN Alll a ON a.request_at = d.request_at AND a.banned = 'No' AND a.status != 'confirmed'
GROUP BY d.request_at
```

Comment: This will not produce a row for any dates not in the original data.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (users_id INT, request_at DATE, status NVARCHAR(20), banned NVARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @Table (users_id, request_at, status, banned) VALUES
(2, '2013-10-01', 'cancelled', 'No '),
(3, '2013-10-01', 'cancelled', 'Yes'),
(4, '2013-10-01', 'cancelled', 'No '),
(5, '2013-10-02', 'confirmed', 'No '),
(6, '2013-10-03', 'cancelled', 'No '),
(7, '2013-10-03', 'cancelled', 'No '),
(8, '2013-10-05', 'cancelled', 'No ');
```

I added a row to your data to demonstrate how a missing date in the data will cause all the other answers to produce an incorrect result.

Consider:

```
;WITH dates AS (
SELECT MIN(request_at) AS Date, MAX(request_at) AS mDate
  FROM @Table
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate
  FROM dates
 WHERE Date < mDate
)

SELECT COUNT(t.users_id) AS count_ban, d.Date
  FROM dates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table t
      ON d.Date = t.request_at
      AND t.banned='No' 
      AND t.status != 'confirmed'
 GROUP BY d.Date
 ORDER BY d.Date
```

Here we're producing a pseudo calendar table which contains ALL the dates covered by the range in your table. We then use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join from it to your data. ALL of the dates now have a row, with the appropriate count.

| count_ban | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2013-10-01 |
| 0 | 2013-10-02 |
| 2 | 2013-10-03 |
| 0 | 2013-10-04 |
| 1 | 2013-10-05 |

Answer (score -1):

You could put the windowed count into a subquery. This way you only scan the table once.

But having said that, it seems you don't need a window function anyway. `DISTINCT` seems wrong here, and probably doesn't do what you think it does. You probably just need to group up the data using `GROUP BY` and then use conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  a.request_at,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN a.banned = 'No' AND a.status <> 'confirmed' THEN 1 END) AS count_ban
FROM Alll a
GROUP BY
  a.request_at;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-u1vSPxJ)

Comment: This will not produce a row for any dates not in the original data.

Comment: Correct, but OP did not ask for that. They asked for `2013-10-02` which was in the original dataset

Comment: A good answer answers the question fully, taking into account as many pitfalls as possible.